# Is it possible change how wordpress displays images when added in a post?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, image, themes

I started making a new WordPress theme with Bootstrap when I stumbled across a problem.

I found out that when I create a new post with some text and an image at the top(Aligned to left) then the image is actually not aligned.
The image is in the top left corner and the text is underneath it.

I searched on Google and read blog posts and so on.
Most people suggest adding some styling in style.css that would align the text.

Example:

```
img.alignright { float: right; margin: 0 0 1em 1em; }
img.alignleft { float: left; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
img.aligncenter { display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; }
```

Of course, this aproach didn't work for me so I checked and I think that the problem is because these classes work only if applied to image tag.
When accessing **the_content()** function, the image is printed inside a div tag.

```
<div id="attachment_66" style="width: 310px" class="wp-caption alignleft">
    <img class="size-medium wp-image-66" src="path/to/img" alt="Sphere" width="300" height="169" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px">
    <p class="wp-caption-text">Who doesn’t like spheres?</p>
</div>
```

If the problem really is because of those  tags, how can I get alignment classes to be applied to img not div tags?

This is how it looks.
[image]

Comment: The `CSS` example you posted is never going to work. You should use `.alignright` instead of `img.alignright`... and so on. Yes, there are ways to tap into the function that generates default code for `<img>` tags in WordPress, by using specific filter hooks but they are highly not recommended. Your users will get frustrated as different snippets they use from WP forums will not work in your theme and they'll down-vote your theme for breaking default WP functionality. Before you develop a WP theme make sure you understand how WP works and what users expect from themes.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Okay, what do you recommend? Have you had a similar problem?

Comment: If you want to float `.alignleft` images you should use `.alignleft { float:left;}`. I don't mean to sound disrespectful of your effort and I only  say this to help you: I believe one cannot build a decent theme before reading  [`The codex`](https://codex.wordpress.org/) at least once, from end to end. If you had to ask the current question, you're probably behind with the aforementioned read. Strong `CSS` knowledge is also required.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thank you! You are right, I haven't read it and if I decide to learn WordPress then I will of course read it.
That one line you provided actually solves my problem.
You should post it as an answer I suppose...

Comment: I actually answered your question in my first comment, if you pay close attention. Fact is I don't want to deter you from your endeavor, and I think you will learn WP much faster by trying to build a theme, even if after finishing it you will already know enough to realize you need to re-code it from scratch, based on what you learned. I authored two WP public plugins and I have the technical background to build a decent theme but never had the guts you seem to have and never went for it. I don't want to stop you. Best of luck!

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Andrei Gheorghiu I managed to solve the issue and I am gonna answer my question.

Premade WordPress themes have some css that I haven't included.

So, this is what you need to include in you style.css

```
.alignleft { float:left;}
.alignright { float:right;}
.aligncenter { display: block; margin: auto; }
```

Comment: Whenever possible, WP is not making assumptions. Their user base is way too large for that. Instead of providing `CSS` which, in some cases, would need to be overridden, they are only providing the classes and give theme developers the liberty of styling those. One theme might use `float`s while others might use `flexbox` for alignment and others will display all images as blocks. This is the theme creator's choice. And, of course, the end user's, who can override it all from a child theme.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the following style:

```
img.alignleft { float: left; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
```

Why don't you create it like:

```
div.alignleft img { float: left; margin: 0 1em 1em 0; }
```

Comment: I just tried it, but it doesn't work. I also tried with !important for each attribute.